# Using SimpleXML to get twitter avatar url (weird)

Tags: php, xml, twitter

Im using simplexml to get the twitter profile avatar url from the xml status page.

this is the code im using

```
<?
$username = twitter;
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/users/".$username.".xml");
echo $xml->user->profile_image_url;
?>
```

The xml page loads when i visit it, but for some reason nothing is being echoed. No errors. Nothing.

When i visit it in a browser, i get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
  <id>783214</id>
  <name>Twitter</name>
  <screen_name>twitter</screen_name>
  <location>San Francisco, CA</location>
  <description>Always wondering what everyone's doing.</description>    
  <profile_image_url>http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/75075164/twitter_bird_profile_normal.png</profile_image_url>
  <url>http://twitter.com</url>.....
  (the rest is long and irrelevant to the question)
```

The data is there, why wont it echo?

Comment: Wow. After reading the answers I *have* to downvote you just for the utter failure of reading the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After loading the XML document, the root element `user` is represented by the `SimpleXMLElement` object saved in `$xml`. Therefore `$xml->user` does not exist.

This one should work:

```
<?
$username = "twitter";  // <-- You did not use quotes here?! Typo?
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/users/".$username.".xml");
echo $xml->profile_image_url;  // <-- No $xml->user here!
?>
```

Comment: So whenever i load an XML file like this, count the first node out?

Comment: For the SimpleXML API, yes. The root node is represented by the object returned by simplexml_load_*().

Answer (score 2):

It is because the root element (in this case, `<user>`) is implied - you do not have to specify it.

Try this:

```
echo $xml->profile_image_url;
```

Answer (score 0):

hey guys - tried out twivatar but I was getting an error 500 error????

anyway here is the code I ended up using - how it is helpful

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['user']))

//if "user" is filled out, get the user's twitter picture 

  {
$username = $_REQUEST['user'];
}else{
$username = 'aplusk';

//else lets use ashton kutcher's picture just for the F of it 

}  // <-- You did not use quotes here?! Typo?
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/users/".$username.".xml");
$timage = $xml->profile_image_url;  // <-- No $xml->user here!
header('location: ' . $timage);
?>
```

Now it is extremely easy to call this script from anywhere in your application simply print ...

```
<img src="http://mywebapp.org/timage.php?user=<php echo $data['twitter_screen_name'];?>" />
```

Answer (score -2):

## Twivatar

Previously, the easiest way to get the twitter avatar was to use Twivatar, which was built by Remy Sharp. However the service has since been shut down.

Using a third party for this is unnecessary.

Comment: Using a third party for this is unnecessary and dangerous.